# Getting data off the Clipboard inside a BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, clipboard

I have a background worker and in the DoWork method I have the following:

```
 var clipboardData = Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Serializable); }));
```

Why does this always return null even though I know there is data on the clipboard in the correct format?

Comment: What is returned if you simply do **Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Serializable)** I suspect it has something to do with the fact your getting the result within a thread after you Invoked it.

Comment: If I don't use the invoke it gives me an exception: System.Threading.ThreadStateException: Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made

Comment: I had the same exception with copying to the clipboard in a BackgroundWorker but adding the invoke fixed it: `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Serializable, theData); }));`

Comment: Do you require to only get the data from Clipboard in the backgroundworker or can you just send it as parameter before calling RunWorkerAsync?

Comment: I need to get the data from the clipboard in a backgroundworker because that is the time intensive operation (it can be a lot of data). I am basically pasting from the clipboard and while that operation is taking place I display a progress dialog.

Comment: That's the chicken-and-egg problem, you are marshaling the call to the UI thread.  The BGW isn't saving you any time.

Comment: Question, is there a reason you are using `Action` and not `Func<T>`? The delegate type `Action` has no return value, but `Func<T>` returns an object of type T.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try putting the call into an STA thread:

```
object data = null;
Thread t = new Thread(() =>
{
    data = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Serializable);
});
t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
t.Start();
t.Join();
// 'data' should be set here.
```

Within a method with an "OnFinished" action:

```
void GetClipboardData(Action<Object> OnFinished)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(() =>
    {
        object data = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Serializable);
        OnFinished(data);
    });
    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    t.Start();
}
```

You'd use it like this:

```
GetClipboardData((data) =>
{
    // 'data' is set to the clipboard data here.
});
```

If you want to show and hide a window, try this:

```
myWindow.Show();
GetClipboardData((data) =>
{
    // Do something with 'data'.
    myWindow.Close();
});
```

With `ShowDialog()`:

```
Thread d = new Thread(() =>
{
    myWindow.ShowDialog();
});
d.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
d.Start();
GetClipboardData((data) =>
{
    // 'data' is set to the clipboard data here.
   myWindow.Close();
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to know when the thread is complete? I am trying to get the clipboard data in the background and display a progress dialog in the foreground. Thus I need to know when it is complete to I can close the progress dialog.

Comment: You can set up an `Action` and call it within the thread, or the `t.Join();` statement will block until the thread completes. I updated my post with a complete method example.

Comment: I'd rather use ShowDialog rather than Show because I don't want the user to be able to do anything on the GUI in the process. But using ShowDialog in this manner with obviously block. Any ideas?

Comment: Put the `ShowDialog()` in yet another thread. Updated the post.